# Phaser JS 3: how to debug game performance

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development

So, I'm working on a project, attempting to learn Phaser as a ruby dev (JS isn't my most confident programming language).

Having run my game on a lower-spec laptop recently, I realised that it kept heating up and the fan was spinning up. Long story short, something about my game is munching the processor.

I don't really know where to start debugging this. Possible lines of enquiry:

- Does Phaser have any tools to tell you what's doing the work?
- Is there a way to make collision events happen once, rather than constantly while in contact?
- Could the update method be called less often for lower-spec machines?
- I've got a large world, then I'm bringing the player window down with the camera. Is there a way to cut the game size down and still scroll to objects off-screen?

Sorry for the vague question, here. I'm just not sure what to do next.

*Note:* The code is available in full here: https://github.com/AJFaraday/night_and_day

Comment: There is a lot of questions in your entry, I don't know by what I should start, maybe the simpler one about collision which you can try to add an if before the collision like if the player's y is lesser then the plattform's one in the basic tutorial example then collide (according to the display that the player's y is lesser when it is on the nearest to the top of the screen. For the other questions your entry is open to discussion I guess so let's discuss here

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to debug performance issues in any Javascript Application is to use the Performance tab in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/) or [Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/performance/). As far as my experience goes, it is the first step any one should follow.

If you plan to develop games using Phaser, you can try to extract some information using a similar way to [this](https://codepen.io/samme/pen/LYVXPRw).

In that example, you can also see how to limit the fps by setting in your game config:

```
fps: {
  forceSetTimeOut: true,
  // panicMax: 0,
  // smoothStep: false,
  target: 15
},
```